libvirt port forwarding to guest: What changed with 10.4.0?
Network/Firewalls isn't my strong side, so there is the possibility that I'm making a very basic mistake.
I need to access services running inside my qemu guest system from other devices in my network. I had a working setup, which stopped working with the upgrade to libvirt 10.4.0. When I downgrade back to 10.3.0 everything works again.
I don't want to be stuck with an old version, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with the new version or why it stopped working at all.
What is happening?
With libvirt 10.4.0 or newer I can't no longer connect to services running inside the guest. I just recieve a "conncetion refused"-error. However I can connect from host to the services inside the guest and from my network devices to services running on the host. The bridging from network to guest-services doesn't seem to work.
My current setup

libvirt running on a Manjaro host
Kernel 6.6.34-1-MANJARO
nftables v1.0.9 (Old Doc Yak #3)
iptables-nft v1.8.10 (nf_tables)
qemu-x86_64 version 9.0.1
libvirt 10.3.0 (working), 10.4.0 (not working), 10.5.0 (not working)

Until recently I was using the following firewall-rules to enable port forwarding to my guest:
iptables-nft -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d 192.168.122.200 -j ACCEPT 
iptables-nft -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.200 -p tcp --dport 5001 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.200:5001
iptables-nft -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.200 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.200:9000 
ip address add 192.168.1.200/24 dev enp7s0

This currently leads to the following filter rules (with libvirt 10.4.0):
$ nft list ruleset                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
table ip libvirt_network {
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                counter packets 36341 bytes 35870777 jump guest_cross
                counter packets 36341 bytes 35870777 jump guest_input
                counter packets 13198 bytes 8954252 jump guest_output
        }

        chain guest_output {
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 iif "virbr0" counter packets 494 bytes 111626 accept
                iif "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
                iif "virbr2" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
                iif "virbr3" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
                ip saddr 10.0.2.0/24 iif "virbr1" counter packets 12704 bytes 8842626 accept
                iif "virbr1" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
        }

        chain guest_input {
                oif "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct state established,related counter packets 1210 bytes 1271061 accept
                oif "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
                oif "virbr2" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
                oif "virbr3" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
                oif "virbr1" ip daddr 10.0.2.0/24 ct state established,related counter packets 21933 bytes 25645464 accept
                oif "virbr1" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
        }

        chain guest_cross {
                iif "virbr0" oif "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iif "virbr2" oif "virbr2" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iif "virbr3" oif "virbr3" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iif "virbr1" oif "virbr1" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }

        chain guest_nat {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 4 bytes 314 return
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 39 bytes 2028 masquerade to :1024-65535
                meta l4proto udp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
                ip saddr 10.0.2.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 3 bytes 236 return
                ip saddr 10.0.2.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 10.0.2.0/24 ip daddr != 10.0.2.0/24 counter packets 4 bytes 208 masquerade to :1024-65535
                meta l4proto udp ip saddr 10.0.2.0/24 ip daddr != 10.0.2.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535
                ip saddr 10.0.2.0/24 ip daddr != 10.0.2.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
        }
}
table ip6 libvirt_network {
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump guest_cross
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump guest_input
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump guest_output
        }

        chain guest_output {
        }

        chain guest_input {
        }

        chain guest_cross {
        }

        chain guest_nat {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        }
}
table inet mozvpn-inet {
        set mozvpn-addrset {
                type ipv4_addr
                elements = { 193.32.248.68 }
        }

        chain mozvpn-cgroup-mark {
                type route hook output priority raw; policy accept;
        }

        chain mozvpn-cgroup-nat {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        }

        chain mozvpn-conntrack {
                type route hook output priority -199; policy accept;
                meta mark 0x0000ca6c ct mark set 0x00009e4c
        }

        chain mozvpn-preroute {
                type filter hook prerouting priority raw; policy accept;
                meta protocol ip meta l4proto udp @nh,96,32 @mozvpn-addrset meta mark set 0x0000ca6c
        }

        chain mozvpn-input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                meta iiftype loopback accept
                iifname "moz0" accept
                meta protocol ip meta l4proto udp @nh,96,32 @mozvpn-addrset accept
                ct mark 0x00009e4c accept
                meta mark 0x0000ca6c accept
                ip6 saddr fc00::/7 accept
                ip6 saddr fe80::/10 accept
                ip6 saddr ff00::/8 accept
                ip saddr 10.0.0.0/8 accept
                ip saddr 172.16.0.0/12 accept
                ip saddr 192.168.0.0/16 accept
                ip saddr 224.0.0.0/4 accept
                udp sport 68 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp dport 67 accept
                udp sport 68 udp dport 67 accept
                ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-router-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
                ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
                ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
                ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-redirect icmpv6 code no-route accept
        }

        chain mozvpn-output {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy drop;
                meta oiftype loopback accept
                oifname "moz0" accept
                meta protocol ip meta l4proto udp @nh,128,32 @mozvpn-addrset accept
                meta mark 0x0000ca6c accept
                ip6 daddr fc00::/7 accept
                ip6 daddr fe80::/10 accept
                ip6 daddr ff00::/8 accept
                ip daddr 10.0.0.0/8 accept
                ip daddr 172.16.0.0/12 accept
                ip daddr 192.168.0.0/16 accept
                ip daddr 224.0.0.0/4 accept
                udp sport 68 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp dport 67 accept
                udp sport 67 udp dport 68 accept
                ip6 daddr ff02::2 icmpv6 type nd-router-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
                ip6 daddr ff02::1:ff00:0/104 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
                ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
                ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
                udp dport 53 reject
                tcp dport 53 reject with tcp reset
        }
}
table ip6 mozvpn-v6 {
        chain mozvpn-preroute-v6 {
                type filter hook prerouting priority raw; policy accept;
                iifname != "moz0" fib saddr type != local ip6 daddr fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01:d:0:e:5f07 drop
        }
}
table ip filter {
        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                ip daddr 192.168.122.200 oifname "virbr0" counter packets 1210 bytes 1271061 accept
                ip daddr 192.168.122.200 oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }
}
# Warning: table ip nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip nat {
        chain PREROUTING {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                ip daddr 192.168.1.200 tcp dport 9000 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "DNAT"
                ip daddr 192.168.1.200 tcp dport 5001 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "DNAT"
        }
}



Is there any chance you could replace the piecemeal output of nft list ... with nft list ruleset? That shows the entire nftables configuration.

Also, dumb question, but is 192.168.122.200 still the correct address for your virtual machine?

You're absolutely within reason to ask such a question. I might be just the guy that makes such a mistake. But yes, 192.168.122.200 is still the correct IP. I'm able to access services within the guest by going to 192.168.122.200:5001 from my host, but 192.168.1.200:5001 from other devices does not work.
I've updated the nft list outputs.

Have you tried enabling tracing to figure out what's going on?

@larsks Probably unnecessary. chain guest_input (used in chain forward of table ip libvirt_network) rejects "new" (forward) traffics that oif "virbr0". Having another table (table ip filter, which is apparently created by iptables-nft) that accepts the traffics will NOT help.

@Tom Yan And what would be the best/the proper way to fix this? I guess the rule is created by libvirt itself - any advice on how to overwrite this the best?

@GediNixan that part I don't know. I have little to no experience with libvirt, but I suppose at the very least, you can manipulate table ip libvirt_network by inserting (i.e. not appending with add) oif "virbr0" accept (or oif "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct state != invalid accept if you like) to either its chain forward or chain guest_input with nft. (Probably you would want to test whether the rule is really sufficient to get the problem fixed first anyway.)


Until recently I was using the following firewall-rules to enable port forwarding to my guest:
iptables-nft -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d 192.168.122.200 -j ACCEPT 
iptables-nft -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.200 -p tcp --dport 5001 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.200:5001
iptables-nft -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.200 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.200:9000 
ip address add 192.168.1.200/24 dev enp7s0


Historically libvirt has used 'iptables' commands to setup firewall rules. On modern distros 'iptables' actually talks to the 'nftables' kernel module
In libvirt 10.4.0, we switched to use the 'nft' command to setup firewall rules by default. As a result the table names that rules appear in all changed. If you're continuing to use 'iptables-nft' for your customizations, those won't get added to the correct nft tables. You'll need to switch to using 'nft' commands (recommended), or manually configure libvirt to go back to using iptables (not recommended).

Thank you for that insight. At least I understand the problem a bit better, but I'm struggling to solve it. As I have only have a very basic understanding of the matter and it seems to have gotten a lot more complicated with nft I can't seem to find the proper place where to put those rules. Could you help me with that? Are those three rules (translated to nft) still enough? And if so: What are the proper tables I need to put them in?

The chain guest_input is the culprit. At least when you have a network of type=nat. When I list the rules there and ask nft to show handles,
[root@localhost ~]# nft -a list table libvirt_network
table ip libvirt_network { # handle 8
        chain forward { # handle 1
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                counter packets 194077 bytes 962460569 jump guest_cross # handle 7
                counter packets 194077 bytes 962460569 jump guest_input # handle 5
                counter packets 48530 bytes 4503133 jump guest_output # handle 3
        }

        chain guest_output { # handle 2
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 iif "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept # handle 65
                iif "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject # handle 62
                ip saddr 192.168.130.0/24 iif "crc" counter packets 197 bytes 39371 accept # handle 55
                iif "crc" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject # handle 52
        }

        chain guest_input { # handle 4
                oif "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct state established,related counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept # handle 66
                oif "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject # handle 63
                oif "crc" ip daddr 192.168.130.0/24 ct state established,related counter packets 175 bytes 143851 accept # handle 56
                oif "crc" counter packets 468 bytes 35808 reject # handle 53
        }

        chain guest_cross { # handle 6
                iif "virbr0" oif "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept # handle 64
                iif "crc" oif "crc" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept # handle 54
        }

        chain guest_nat { # handle 8
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return # handle 71
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return # handle 70
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535 # handle 69
                meta l4proto udp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535 # handle 68
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade # handle 67
                ip saddr 192.168.130.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return # handle 61
                ip saddr 192.168.130.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return # handle 60
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.130.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.130.0/24 counter packets 13 bytes 780 masquerade to :1024-65535 # handle 59
                meta l4proto udp ip saddr 192.168.130.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.130.0/24 counter packets 1 bytes 76 masquerade to :1024-65535 # handle 58
                ip saddr 192.168.130.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.130.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade # handle 57
        }
}

and then delete the offending rule that blocks input to my crc network by its handle, packets started flowing (in both directions).
nft delete rule libvirt_network guest_input handle 53

I don't have a final solution to this problem yet, but switching from nat network to a route network, as described in https://lukas.zapletalovi.com/posts/2022/easy-vm-access-with-routed-libvirt-mode/ seems to work better for me.

As I said, libvirt comes with NAT network, the configuration looks like this
[...]
Let’s simply edit the XML configuration to change it into route mode. Let’s perform two changes: change forward mode to route and pick a different subnet address (122 is comonly used so let’s use 200).

